# Better to repair a CVT or replace with a used one?

Tags: honda, transmission, civic, automatic-transmission

Our 2003 Honda Civic Hybrid transmission died. Honda gave us an estimate of $4500 to replace the transmission. We took it to a different mechanic who suggested that instead of replacing the whole transmission, it would be better to fix it. He quoted us $3200 to fix it and $2700 to replace the transmission with a used part.

He strongly suggested we fix instead of replace, since the replacement part could go bad again. He also gives a 2 year warranty if we fix, but only 6 month if we replace.

What has me worried is that we've been driving on this bad transmission for a while. Apparently he is only replacing the belt and the start clutch, and not actually replacing the parts that have been being damaged by the problems. We needed the car this week, and I thought that since he'd be fixing it any way, it would be fine to drive on the bad transmission, but he said it would be damaging it further. But the thing is that we've already been damaging it for a long time.

What are your thoughts--is it better to risk it with an unknown used transmission, or fix the bad parts of our existing transmission, knowing that it's been slightly damaged?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I look at it you are paying $500 for 18 more months of warranty. If the parts he doesn't replace are damaged they won't make it 2 years. When you rebuild a transmission you don't replace all the parts, just the parts that are needed. If it makes it 2 years it didn't need to be replaced, if it doesn't it's his problem.

I would go with the rebuilt because the used is unknown, it might last 10 years or 181 days, for me it's not worth the risk. At least with the rebuild you have some new parts (the ones that wear out under normal operation) and of course the longer warranty.

Comment: Larry's answer is sound reasoning I my book.

Answer (score 0):

I just over cvt transmission it is not hard at all. Master rebuild kits includes forward clutches, reverse clutches and start clutches. I think it is so easy then other auto transmission.  Parts only $500.